# Insertion at end in doubly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am inserting a node at the end of a doubly linked list, but the output is only showing the first and the last element.

```
void insertend(int y) {

    // y the element to be inserted<br>
    // head is declared as global 

   node *ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   node *ptr1=head;
   ptr->info=y;

   if(head==NULL) {
       ptr->next=ptr->prev=head;
       head=ptr;
   } 
   else {

       ptr->prev=ptr1;
       ptr->next=NULL;
       ptr1->next=ptr;
       ptr1=ptr;
   }

}
 void showtail() {
   node *ptr=head;
   while(ptr!=NULL) {
       printf("%d\n",ptr->info);
       ptr=ptr->next;
   }
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please fix formatting and show us how do you test your program.

Comment: you can run a debugger for such doubts

Comment: while posting your code show your structure also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it...

```
 if(head==NULL)
 {
    ptr->next=ptr->prev=head;
   head=ptr;
  }
 else
 {
   while(ptr1->next!=NULL)
    ptr1=ptr1->next;
   ptr->prev=ptr1;
   ptr->next=NULL;
   ptr1->next=ptr;
   ptr1=ptr;
  }
```

You have to traverse before  every insertion up to the last node. Otherwise, you have to maintain ptr1 as the static variable.

Answer (score 1):

When your are trying to insert the element in the DLL (or) SLL at the end,you need to `traverse upto the end of the list`

else you need to maintain the pointer for the Last Inserted node.

But in this code your always insert elements after the first node, That is why your getting the first node and the last node as the output.